# Histogram color fills with categorical variables in R

Tags: r, histogram, categorical-data

I am trying to create a plot like this:

```
qplot(carat, data = diamonds, geom = "histogram", fill = color)
```

However, instead of having a quantitative variable for the x-axis, I am using a categorical data. I am using a data frame like this:

```
refBases=c("A","A","A","C","C","C","G","G","G","T","T","T")
altBases=c("C","G","T","A","G","T","A","C","T","A","C","G")
myDF$ref=refBases
myDF$alt=altBases
myDF$Freq=c(5,2,3,6,9,6,8,6,7,4,6,4)
```

So, basically, I would like my plot to look the same, except that the x-axis will be four bins from the ref column (A,C,G,T); the y-axis will be the Freq; and the color legend will be the four variables in the alt column (A,C,G,T). So, basically, there will be four ref bins on the x-axis, each divided into three parts along the y-axis, with the color legend indicating the alt value.

I get something rather silly when I try what I expect:

```
qplot(ref,Freq,data=myDF,fill=alt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing doesn't sound like a histogram (which is a very specific plot for continuous random variables to estimate the kernel density); sounds like you just want a bar chart. I believe this is what you're looking for

```
myDF <- data.frame(
    ref=c("A","A","A","C","C","C","G","G","G","T","T","T"),
    alt=c("C","G","T","A","G","T","A","C","T","A","C","G"),
    Freq=c(5,2,3,6,9,6,8,6,7,4,6,4)
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(myDF, aes(ref, Freq, fill=alt)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]